# How to make tolua++ call custom code in collect function

Tags: c++, lua, garbage-collection, tolua++

The title pretty much explains it all.
I don't want tolua++ to generate code that just calls

```
delete self;
```

in collect function. I want it to do something like this:

```
some_custom_collector(self);
```

Is this possible to specify in .pkg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days I was back on this problem, and I needed quick solution. I realized that there is no way to do this. So I made a patch for tolua++, but for version I found in CEGUI source. **So it was done in really ugly way, but it's pretty easy to use and it works**.

Suppose you have class SomeClass, and you want lua function delete and collect function to call SomeClass_CustomFinalizer, you can specify that in you SomeClass.pkg file like this:

```
tolua_outside void ~SomeClass @ SomeClass_CustomFinalizer();
```

so instead of generating code like this:

```
delete self;
```

it will generate code like this:

```
SomeClass_CustomFinalizer(self);
```

Here is patch. Even if you fail to apply it, it should be pretty easy to get the general idea and apply manually.

```
diff --git a/lua/basic.lua b/lua/basic.lua
index 99fc961..b4983e3 100644
--- a/lua/basic.lua
+++ b/lua/basic.lua
@@ -67,7 +67,8 @@ _basic_raw_push = {}
 _usertype = {}

 -- List of types that have to be collected
-_collect = {}
+_collect = {{}}
+_collect_custom_finalizers_index = 1

 -- List of types
 _global_types = {n=0}

diff --git a/lua/class.lua b/lua/class.lua
index 8580ce8..c8f275e 100644
--- a/lua/class.lua
+++ b/lua/class.lua
@@ -78,7 +78,10 @@ function classClass:requirecollection (t)
    -- classes that export constructors need to have a collector (overrided by -D flag on command line)
    if self._delete or ((not flags['D']) and self._new) then
        --t[self.type] = "tolua_collect_" .. gsub(self.type,"::","_")
-       t[self.type] = "tolua_collect_" .. clean_template(self.type)
+        t[self.type] = "tolua_collect_" .. clean_template(self.type)
+        if self.custom_finalizer then
+          t[_collect_custom_finalizers_index][self.type] = self.custom_finalizer
+        end
        r = true
    end
  return r

diff --git a/lua/function.lua b/lua/function.lua
index ce73cf8..0db9b2f 100644
--- a/lua/function.lua
+++ b/lua/function.lua
@@ -322,7 +322,11 @@ function classFunction:supcode (local_constructor)

  -- call function
  if class and self.name=='delete' then
-  output('  delete self;')
+   if self.custom_finalizer then
+       output('  ' .. self.custom_finalizer .. '(self);')
+   else
+       output('  delete self;')
+   end
  elseif class and self.name == 'operator&[]' then
   if flags['1'] then -- for compatibility with tolua5 ?
    output('  self->operator[](',self.args[1].name,'-1) = ',self.args[2].name,';')


@@ -679,14 +684,20 @@ function _Function (t)

  append(t)
  if t:inclass() then
- --print ('t.name is '..t.name..', parent.name is '..t.parent.name)
+
+--print ('t.name is '..t.name..', parent.name is '..t.parent.name)
+
   if string.gsub(t.name, "%b<>", "") == string.gsub(t.parent.original_name or t.parent.name, "%b<>", "") then
    t.name = 'new'
    t.lname = 'new'
    t.parent._new = true
    t.type = t.parent.name
    t.ptr = '*'
-  elseif string.gsub(t.name, "%b<>", "") == '~'..string.gsub(t.parent.original_name or t.parent.name, "%b<>", "") then
+ elseif string.gsub(t.name, "%b<>", "") == '~'..string.gsub(t.parent.original_name or t.parent.name, "%b<>", "") then
+   if t.lname ~= t.name then
+     t.parent.custom_finalizer = t.lname
+     t.custom_finalizer = t.lname
+   end
    t.name = 'delete'
    t.lname = 'delete'
    t.parent._delete = true

diff --git a/lua/package.lua b/lua/package.lua
index 6ba30fb..edc791a 100644
--- a/lua/package.lua
+++ b/lua/package.lua
@@ -135,12 +135,20 @@ function classPackage:preamble ()
        output('/* function to release collected object via destructor */')
        output('#ifdef __cplusplus\n')
        for i,v in pairs(_collect) do
-        output('\nstatic int '..v..' (lua_State* tolua_S)')
-           output('{')
-           output(' '..i..'* self = ('..i..'*) tolua_tousertype(tolua_S,1,0);')
-           output('    delete self;')
-           output('    return 0;')
-           output('}')
+            if i ~= _collect_custom_finalizers_index then
+
+            output('\nstatic int '..v..' (lua_State* tolua_S)')
+            output('{')
+            output(' '..i..'* self = ('..i..'*) tolua_tousertype(tolua_S,1,0);')
+            if _collect[_collect_custom_finalizers_index][i] then
+                output('  ' .. _collect[_collect_custom_finalizers_index][i] .. '(self);')
+            else
+                output('  delete self;')
+            end
+            output('   return 0;')
+            output('}')
+
+            end
        end
        output('#endif\n\n')
    end
```

You should remake binding code for tolua++ and recompile it.